# Meteor: Hide properties from client

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to exclude certain properties from client updates?

It should not be possible to see the property when inspecting a collection in the console

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Absolutely.

1. Remove the `autopublish` package which is turned on by default: `meteor remove autopublish`
2. Create your collection: `Rooms = new Meteor.Collection("rooms");` *No conditional isServer or isClient needed, as this should be present to both*
3. In your server side code, [publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) only a subset of your collection by zeroing out the fields you don't want the client to have:

   ```
   if (Meteor.isServer) {
       //you could also Rooms.find({ subsetId: 'some_id' }) a subset of Rooms
       Meteor.publish("rooms", function () {
           return Rooms.find({}, {fields: {secretInfo: 0}});
       });
   }
   ```

   NOTE: setting `{secretInfo: 0}` above does not set all instances of `secretInfo` for every row in the `Rooms` collection to zero. It **removes** the field altogether from the clientside collection. Think of `0` as the off switch :)
4. Subscribe client side to the published collection:

   ```
   if (Meteor.isClient) {
       Deps.autorun(function() {
           Meteor.subscribe("rooms");
       });
   }
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was looking for a `view` option in `Collection.allow`, seems like that would make more sense. But this is also an elegant way to do it.

Comment: Perfect answer, TimDog!! Thanks a lot... I think I was on the right track, but ignored the message meteor was giving me regarding the removal of autosubscribe

Comment: Is this subsetId documented somewhere?

Comment: What's the `Meteor.autosubscribe` function? I don't see it in the documentation - is it deprecated?

Comment: Yes, this is deprecated -- use `Deps.autorun` now! I've updated this answer